# Convert raw v4l2 buffer to QVideoframe in qt

Tags: qt, qpainter, qlabel, v4l2, qtmultimedia

I will get raw video data from the V4L2 driver using VIDIOC_DQBUF, I wanted to render this frame in qt using QVideoFrame(which construct video frame) and QLabel/QPaint(for rendering a video frame).

> QVideoFrame::QVideoFrame(QAbstractVideoBuffer *buffer, const QSize &size, QVideoFrame::PixelFormat format)
>   Constructs a video frame from a buffer with the given pixel format and size in pixels.
>   [Qvideoframe from Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#details)

As of now, I’m using QImage to rendering RGB24 and QImage supports the only RGB format. However raw video frame which is received from VIDIOC_DQBUF is having different color formats and  QVideoFrame support most of them.

Queries:

1. How to use QVideoFrame::QVideoFrame(QAbstractVideoBuffer *buffer, const QSize &size, QVideoFrame::PixelFormat format) for v4l2 buffer ?
2. How I can use map(), bits() and mappedBytes() function so that, I can get QVideoFrame constructed for given raw video data?
3. How I can use QPaint/QLabel to render QVideoFrame?

Regards,
Kulakrni

Answer (score 0):

Lets reverse the order.

> How I can use QPaint/QLabel to render QVideoFrame?

You can not.  You need to use a `QAbstractVideoSurface()` derived class.  In QML, this is `VideoOutput`.  If you want a single image, then `QVideoFrame` is not the correct class to use for QPaint/QLabel.

> How I can use map(), bits() and mappedBytes() function so that, I can get QVideoFrame constructed for given raw video data?

These functions are your interface to the `QAbstractVideoSurface`.  It depends on how you want to store the VL4 buffer.  Are you copying/translating it or are you mapping it directly; then there are ownership issues which this API attempts to address.

> How to use QVideoFrame::QVideoFrame(QAbstractVideoBuffer *buffer, const QSize &size, QVideoFrame::PixelFormat format) for v4l2 buffer

You need to sub-class a `QAbstractVideoBuffer` by either copying/translating the data and keeping it with the class or provide a reference if you are using zero-copy of some sort.

---

By default, QML `Camera` and `QCamera` will find and use `/dev/videoX` which is a v4l device, via GStreamer.  This class should already *do the right thing* to supply a `VideoOutput` widget.

See: [Qt Video overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html)